# Added "Full Control" access rule for registry key applies to nothing

Tags: powershell, registry

I've crafted the following script to grant "FullControl" access to one of my Registry keys for my local user:

```
$userName = "MyUser"
$keyPath = "HKLM:\Software"
$keyName = "MyApp"
$keyFullPath = (Join-Path -Path $keyPath -ChildPath $keyName)

function GrantFullControlOverTheRegistryKey
{
    $registryRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::FullControl
    $inheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit
    $propagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::InheritOnly
    $accessType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
    
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule($userName, $registryRights, $inheritanceFlags, $propagationFlags, $accessType)
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $keyFullPath

    Write-Output "$(TimeStamp) Granting Full Control access to $keyFullPath for $userName user 1/2..."
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    
    Write-Output "$(TimeStamp) Granting Full Control access to $keyFullPath for $userName user 2/2..."
    Set-Acl -Path $keyFullPath $acl
    
    Write-Output "$(TimeStamp) Full Control access to $keyFullPath successfully granted for $userName user."
}

if (!(Test-Path $keyFullPath))
{
    Write-Output "$(TimeStamp) Creating $keyFullPath subkey..."
    New-Item -Path $keyPath -Name $keyName
    GrantFullControlOverTheRegistryKey
}
```

After running the above script I can see my rule in Registry Editor but it has nothing checked.
[image]

When I look into "Advanced" options it says that the rule applies to "Nothing".
[image]

Is something wrong with my script or am I missing something important?